# Jenkins build based on changes

Tags: jenkins

How to achieve below issue.

I'm using multi scm in jenkins

How to execute build based on repo changes

Ex:- if repo1 is changed execute date

if repo2 is changed execute whoami

if repo3 having changes execute pwd.

Comment: Jenkins documentation is pretty good have you gone through it?

Comment: yeah but i'm not understanding and i forgot to mention i'm trying the above with freestyle job

Comment: What is the real use case which should be handle? Do you want to do only that for practice only?

Comment: we have n no.of repos for each repo creating a jenkins job doesn't make sense so we are using multi scm in our org, our requirement is need to run a script based on repo change